# Write in Hbase with Spark 2.3 and assign timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I am writing in Hbase using HBase-Spark connector, but I want to assign a Timestamp to each row based in a column in the DS. It is possible to do such thing? Here is an example of what I a want to do

```
case class Person(name: String,
email: String,
date: Long)

import spark.implicits._

val personDS =  Seq(Person("alice", "alice@alice.com", 1577836800000L), Person("bob", "bob@bob.com", 1609459200000L)).toDS()
personDS.write.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark")
.option("hbase.columns.mapping", "name STRING :key, email STRING c:email, date Long c:date_to_remove")
.option("hbase.table", "person")
.option("hbase.spark.use.hbasecontext", false)
.save()
```

Each row must have the timestamp of date value

Regards

This is what insert the code

```
alice                                    column=c:date_to_remove, timestamp=1695042159830, value=\x00\x00\x01\x8A\xA7\xF2\xA3\x11                              
 alice                                    column=c:email, timestamp=1695042159830, value=alice@alice.com                                                        
 bob                                      column=c:date_to_remove, timestamp=1695042159674, value=\x00\x00\x01\x8A\xA7\xF2\xA3\x11                              
 bob                                      column=c:email, timestamp=1695042159674, value=bob@bob.com
```

and I want (I only insert date_to_remove right now because all the columns must be in the mapping)

```
 alice                                    column=c:email, timestamp=1577836800000, value=alice@alice.com                                                                              
 bob                                      column=c:email, timestamp=1609459200000, value=bob@bob.com
```

@ziya-mert-karakas with your answer the mapping need to be

```
        .option("hbase.columns.mapping", "name STRING :key, email STRING c:email, timestamp Long c:date_to_remove, date Long c:date")
```

and the result is

```
 alice                                    column=c:date, timestamp=1695210586700, value=\x00\x00\x01o^f\xE8\x00                                                 
 alice                                    column=c:date_to_remove, timestamp=1695210586700, value=\x00\x00\x01o^f\xE8\x00                                       
 alice                                    column=c:email, timestamp=1695210586700, value=alice@alice.com                                                        
 bob                                      column=c:date, timestamp=1695210586753, value=\x00\x00\x01v\xBB>p\x00                                                 
 bob                                      column=c:date_to_remove, timestamp=1695210586753, value=\x00\x00\x01v\xBB>p\x00                                       
 bob                                      column=c:email, timestamp=1695210586753, value=bob@bob.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In HBase, you can set a custom timestamp for each cell while writing data using the HBase-Spark connector; to achieve this, you'll need to modify your dataframe before writing it to HBase. The timestamp in this example is based on your date column.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val personDS = Seq(Person("alice", "alice@alice.com", 1577836800000L), Person("bob", "bob@bob.com", 1609459200000L)).toDS()

// this creates a new dF with the custom timestamp column using withColumn.
val personWithTimestamp = personDS.withColumn("timestamp", col("date"))

// writes the dF to Hbase with the custom timestamp
personWithTimestamp.write
  .format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark")
  .option("hbase.columns.mapping", "name STRING :key, email STRING c:email, timestamp Long c:date_to_remove")
  .option("hbase.table", "person")
  .option("hbase.spark.use.hbasecontext", false)
  .save()
```

We create a new DataFrame personWithTimestamp by adding a custom timestamp column based on the date column. This timestamp column will be used to set the timestamps for HBase cells. Then we write to Hbase with the custom timestamp column. This way, each row in the HBase table will have the specified timestamp for the cells in the date_to_remove column family, as you intended.

Comment: Thanks,but if I understand you right it does not do what you said, with your code it will only add the timestamp value to the column c:date_to_remove, and you need to add all the columns in the mapping or it will throw an error.
What I need is to change the timestamp of the column to my value